# How to change view for label

Tags: swift, animation, storyboard, xib

I have a `UILabel` and I want to change its background view. Somebody advised me to use bezier but I want a simple variant.

My label:

[image: it is my lable]

What it should look like:

[image: what should look like]

Comment: Easiest non-code solution would be to create an image and use it as background. For non-fixed width, you could have three images: left, middle (stretchable), right and put those in a horizontal stack view, where the label would be inside the middle image view, thus determining the width.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since these are not very complex shapes, I would suggest creating two white `UIView`s, rotating them 45 degrees and then adding them as subviews to the `UILabel`. The code would look something like this:

```
    myLabel.clipsToBounds = true
    // create the triangle on the left side of the label
    let leftSquare = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: myLabel.frame.height / -2, y: 0, width: myLabel.frame.height, height: myLabel.frame.height))
    leftSquare.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
    leftSquare.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    leftSquare.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    leftSquare.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi / 4)) // 45 degree rotation
    // create the triangle on the right side of the cell
    let rightSquare = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: myLabel.bounds.width - (myLabel.frame.height / 2), y: 0, width: myLabel.frame.height, height: myLabel.frame.height))
    rightSquare.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
    rightSquare.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    rightSquare.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    rightSquare.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi / 4))
    // add squares to label
    myLabel.addSubview(leftSquare)
    myLabel.addSubview(rightSquare)
    myLabel.sendSubview(toBack: leftSquare)
    myLabel.sendSubview(toBack: rightSquare)
```

Comment: instead of cell in height should be my label name?

Comment: myLabel.frame.height

Comment: how swift understands that this should happen at the edges of the label

Comment: Oh I'm sorry I misread your question initially. Yes, the right and left squares would need to have a `width` and `height` of `myLabel.frame.height`.

Comment: I have 2 labels

Comment: everywhere instead of cell using myLabel?

Comment: You are going to want to use the height the `UILabel` that has the grey background. Swift understands that this should happen at the edge of the label since I set `leftSquare`'s frame origin.x as 0 and then `rightSquare`'s frame origin.x as the width of the label. You can use this code once anywhere after you have setup the label and added the text.

Comment: Yes, you can ignore the `cell` answer I initially had - you will want to use the name of your `UILabel` variable instead.

Comment: I would suggest doing some basic debugging to see why its not working. You can try to print out all of the subviews of the `UILabel` with `for subview in myLabel.subviews { print (subview.debugDescription) }` and see why it isn't working.

Comment: Hi, I have edited the solution I proposed to you to make it work properly with Swift 4. Please replace the previous code I provided with this new edit and it should work.

Comment: I can't send you any image im comment, how I can to connect with you? your solution is almost correct

Comment: I use myLabel.numberOfLines = 0, and view height will be more

Comment: I can't get proportional size on different phones, the same size appears everywhere, how to set constraints?

Comment: You will want to add the square subviews after you set the `text` of the `UILabel` - i.e. once the height has been calculated. You can do this with constraints if you set the square subviews `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true` and then set the constraints accordingly.